# how to use a single HTML file for different screen sizes?

Tags: android, html, css

I am developing an application in which I have used a HTML file. In my application, for one activity I enabled the title bar and in this activity I have loaded a HTML file in webview and the HTML page fits the emulator screen. In another activity I have  hidden the title bar and loaded the same HTML file in this activity. In second case there is some space in bottom of the screen. Can anyone please let me know the solution for this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please add more details in your question?

Comment: Please post your relevant code. It's unclear if it's the WebView that doesn't fill all the space, leaving  space at the bottom or if it's just that there isn't enough HTML content to fill all the space...

Comment: This [article](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) might help you. Be more specific about your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your question, is that it is irrelevant.

You can use a single HTML file for different screen sizes because it makes no difference. It is the CSS which is important here.

You could define multiple css stylesheets, one for each screen size, and define javascript to listen to see what the screen size is.

However, if you won't be building a mobile version (very small screen), then you should simply use a **fluid css layout** using relative positioning and percentage widths.

A super-basic quick example of a fluid dynamic layout that changes with screen size might be:

HTML

```
<html>
  <body>
   <div id="first"></div>
   <div id="second"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
}
#first {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: #eee;
}
#second {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Media queries in CSS targeting custom width.